# Resizeable div with background image

Tags: html, css

I have a div with a background image:

```
<div id="myDiv">
   ...
</div>

#myDiv {
   background-image: url(...);
   width: 70%;
   max-width: 200px;
}
```

Now, I want my background image to be resized to fit the div. To do this, a added background-size: 100%. This solves the problem regarding width, but the height only accomodates the content of the, and since the content of this div is smaller, the image is cropped in the bottom. What should I set for the height attribute so that it follows the resizing of the width?

Comment: could you use `background-size:cover`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand well, you want the background to be streched and fit exactely to the div. In that case, try to set both values of the background-size property in this way:

```
background-size: 100% 100%;
```

Comment: Hm, I forgot to add one detail. This background-image is for a button so it has two parts one above another, one to show normally and one for :active pseudo selector. So if I put background-size: 100% 100%; the whole image is scaled and resized so that both parts are visible.

Comment: So in that case try `background-size: 100% 200%;`